# How to fit images in viewport?

Tags: html, css, image

For the [given source code of webpage](http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/examples/1-08/imageRelativeWidth/index-quiz.html):

Here is the modified css:

```
img {
   float: left; /* existing line of code */
   width: calc(98%/3);
}
img#img1 {
  margin-right:10px;
} 
img#img2 {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

But the test results are not successful.

After css code changes, Why is the right image still flushed against viewport? as shown below:

[image]

*Note: CSS code changes recommended only*

Answer (score 2):

You need to subtract `20px` to account for the `10px` margins on each side of the second image:

```
img {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
}
```

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
}
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/200" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200" />
<img src="//placehold.it/200" />
```

Comment: If your solution is correct, then, the all the test results should be green on webpage(top-right)

Comment: @overexchange Nope. I didn't change any HTML. http://i.stack.imgur.com/FCKzR.png I just posted the HTML above as an example!

Comment: you wrote type rule(`img{}`), twice. So, am not clear with the answer

Comment: @overexchange That doesn't mean that I changed the HTML. In your code above, you wrote it out three times. Did you try adding `width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3)` to the `img` elements? That's the only part that is really different from our examples. I can assure you that it works...

Comment: No it does not work in my case [here](https://github.com/shamhub/CSS_styling/blob/master/Topic15_media_queries/scn.png)

Comment: @overexchange I'm not sure why, because this is what I am getting: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zUQKW.png

Answer (score 0):

@Josh Crozier @overexchange The code provided by @Josh Crozier solve the problem, and could be made with #imgid too, and others way. for this part of the course both answers are good enough.

@overexchange after checking your code i can see there is no space between the () and /3 like this:

```
img {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 20px)/3);
}
```

this is making the css3 fail the calculations, like on media queries the space is necessary ex:
@media screen and (query){} -> work @media screen and(query){} -> doesn't work

edit: i mean doesn't work on every port, the awkward part is the professor make the same thing you did on the answer

so this would be a acceptable answer

```
img {
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 20px) / 3);
}
img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

sorry for answering so late i just come across this post now, but will leave it there for anyone struggling with this...
i probably made a few English mistakes sorry about that too it's not my native language, good luck